# Can't put boolean type in TypeScript select tag

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble getting the value of the select tag and option tag to contain boolean types in Type Script.

I get the following error with the boolean tag because this tag should contain string.

> Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.

The code:

```js
<select
  defaultValue={true}
  onChange={(e) => setIsSelected(e.target.value)}
>
  <option value={true}>Yes</option>
  <option value={false}>No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`option` doesn't accept boolean type so try to use 0 vs 1 or "true" vs "false" in your code.